# How do i execute shell script using java

Tags: java, linux, bash

How do I execute shell script file with an input parameter like "./flows.sh suspend" and print the the result to a file using java in linux?

Comment: _"please reply entire code if possible"_ -- this is guaranteed to attract downvotes and get your question closed.  StackOverflow is not a "give me teh codez" site and asking for code without showing any effort at all is considered rude and off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple code to execute the shell script and read its output:

```
import java.io.*;                                                            

public class Test {                                                          
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                  
    String[] command = { "./flows.sh", "suspend" };         
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);                    
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(    
        process.getInputStream()));                                          
    String s;                                                                
    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {                                
      System.out.println("Script output: " + s); // Replace this line with the code to print the result to file                     
    }                                                                        
  }                                                                          
}
```

To print it to a file, just replace the System.out.println for the code to write into a file

Comment: It's.... somewhat more complex than this.  Just for starters, what does `./` refer to, and where does the shell figure into this?

Comment: @JimGarrison `./` refers to the current directory, and it's required to suppress PATH lookup. The shell that interprets the script is spawned by the kernel based on the script's shebang. There's not more to it than this, and it can be done even more easily with ProcessBuilder to set up a redirection straight to the file.

Comment: @JimGarrison That is another question... I just put a working solution on how to execute a shell script from java and get its output because I considered it as the main problem

Answer (score -1):

You can use the  JSCH API:

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Shell.java.html
http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html

Bye!